# Installing 3rd party App

Tags: appexchange, insufficient-privileges

I'm working with a vendor, and we are having problems installing the app in our sandbox environment.  I've given the vendor full access (System Admin) but there is still error.  The error message is:

> Insufficient Privileges: You do not have the level of access necessary
>   to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
>   the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: what is the name of the app and the Role that the vendor is setup with?

Comment: The app is Lean Data and the role is Admin and profile system admin. Thanks

Comment: does the user also have the same admin access in production and the sandbox?

Comment: no, the user have system admin in sandbox but not production.

Comment: Doesn't the vendor provide support ?

Comment: Thank you all.  Our Vendor got this resolved.  I will ask him what he did and post the answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your issue is because the User must login to production for install first even if they are installing it in the sandbox. They must have the privileges in a production environment, so if the user is missing permissions in Production it doesn't matter that they have full access to the Sandbox, they will not be able to install. Try changing the vendors permissions in production to System Admin or granting them the Download AppExchange Packages permission set to the vendor's user profile.

I also saw a post from 2013 that said users can log into a free developer account where they have full System Admin Production rights and install the app using the developer account login for the Production part. Then you will be able to install it in your sandbox. Salesforce doesn't check to make sure the companies match. https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hkR1AAI

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce administrators and users with the “Download AppExchange packages” permission can install AppExchange apps.